# SOQL SUM() function not calculating the correct value

Tags: soql, aggregate, sum

I have a SOQL query that I'm trying to use the SUM function with. My issue is that the SUM function gives me a totally different result than if i just query the rows and add up the amounts

Query 1 - Selecting the rows individually

```
select id,  Parts_Cost__c from customObject where Status= 'Completed' 
and Contract = :contractId and Completed_On__c >= :contractStartDate  
and Completed_On__c <= :contractEndDate
```

The individual results for parts cost sum to- 6773.59 and 17 rows are returned

Query 2- Aggregate Results:

```
select count(id),  sum(Parts_Cost__c) from customObject where Status= 'Completed'
and Contract = :contractId and Completed_On__c >= :contractStartDate  
and Completed_On__c <= :contractEndDate
```

This will give me a summed value of 8036.05 and the count result is 17 rows.

Can anyone think of reasons for these discrepancies in the results? Can I see how the 8036.05 is getting calculated?

Comment: where do you run these SOQLs?

Comment: They are running in an Apex Class that I have created, but i've also run them in the workbench to verify the results and am getting the same issue there

Comment: You may be missing  something,

Comment: Just soql only select Parts_Cost__c  from customObject where  ***..  & check the reuslt .

Comment: Just to be sure, the variables that you're using to filter your query are the same in both cases, correct? (e.g. `contractId`, `contractStartDate`, and `contractEndDate`). That would be the easiest explanation for the difference. When using aggregate functions, we lose the ability to see the individual records that were pulled by the query, so for purposes of testing it would make sense to hardcode values into your 3 variables there (alternatively, run both queries in the same transaction).

Comment: When I tried this in the workbench I used hard coded values for the contractId, the Start Date and the End Date for both queries and got the different results. The only thing out of the ordinary in this is that the fields are roll up summaries, but i'm not sure that this should create this effect

Comment: Do you have multi-currency enabled? Is your record in a value different than the corporate default currency? I might wonder if that could be the cause.

Comment: @sfdcfox This was the reason, these records are stored in our secondary currency and the difference between the two was exactly the exchange rate. Can I use the SUM function and set the currency I want the result in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Querying Currency Fields in Multi-Currency Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm). Any time you use an aggregate function, it is always in the organization's currency.

> You can’t convert the result of an aggregate function into the user’s currency by calling the convertCurrency() function. If a query includes a GROUP BY or HAVING clause, currency data returned by using an aggregate function, such as SUM() or MAX(), is in the org’s default currency.

So, if you want the values in the user's currency, you can use the convertCurrency function, but you have to do the math yourself:

```
select id, convertCurrency(Parts_Cost__c) from customObject where Status= 'Completed' 
and Contract = :contractId and Completed_On__c >= :contractStartDate  
and Completed_On__c <= :contractEndDate

...

Decimal total = 0;
for(customObject record: queryResults) {
    total += record.Parts_Cost__c;
}
```

You can't choose to get values in currency values other than the organization's currency or the user's currency.